# Effects of returning FALSE or TRUE in index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I don't know if the heading explains my problem , I'm trying to figure out what are the pro and cons of returning FALSE or TRUE from the index.php file in your controller .
and serious I have tried googled with no luck.

Example :

```
Class MY_MAIN_controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        // My constructor 
    }
    function index() {
        // example trying calling some function from another class I have in my project
        if ( ! $this->user_is_in()) {
            // Do something
            return FALSE;
        }
        // calling something else 
        if ( ! $this->user_is_active() {
            // Do something
            return FALSE;
        }
        if ($this->user_is_admin() {
            // Do something
            return FALSE; // or maybe return TRUE
        }
        $this->load->view->('home'); 
        // Then maybe return TRUE or FALSE
    }
}
```

Now what are effects of TRUE and FALSE commands on the code .?
Is it a bad practice doing that . ?

Comment: It depends if whatever is invoking your controller and these methods checks (cares about) the return value.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by (checks (cares about) the return value)

Comment: It can also cease further processing if one of those conditions is met.

Comment: I think it is a bad practice doing this because whenever any if condition is met then from that point the function will return and view will not be loaded. view will be loaded only when any one of the if condition does not meet.

Comment: Meaning from other controller's invoking my_main_controller .? @KaiQing

Comment: So whats your suggestion if I want to terminate the if statement or any other operation without affecting the flow (assume the above flow) till I call the view . ? @www.sblog.in

Comment: @RobyMi depending on your if condition you can load view or you can store the outcome from if condition in a variable and pass that variable to the view for further processing.